# Get value from matrix based on address from two other tables in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to construct a table C that gets values from a set matrices X, Y and Z based on the "address" given in two other tables A and B.

To do this I've first added ID columns to tables A and B by:

```
A$A.ID <- seq.int(nrow(A))
B$B.ID <- seq.int(nrow(B))
```

and found all the permutations of the IDs using:

```
C <- expand.grid(A$A.ID, B$B.ID)
```

Now I want to add a columns X, Y and Z to C but have no idea what i'm doing (pretty new to programming :/ )

To explain the process I've drawn a picture. Hopefully it helps...

[image]

Let me know if you need to know anything else.

Comment: I know it's probably a right pain, but if you could provide reproducible examples of A/B/X/Y/Z and a C of the intended result (the data sets can just be 3 or 4 rows each) you'd be much more likely to get code in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works going by the pattern you describe. First of all, here's some example data:

```
A <- data.frame(A.ID=1:2, X=1:2, Y=3:2, Z=2:1)
B <- data.frame(B.ID=1:2, X=1:2, Y=2:1, Z=1:2)

A;B
#  A.ID X Y Z
#1    1 1 3 2
#2    2 2 2 1

#  B.ID X Y Z
#1    1 1 2 1
#2    2 2 1 2

X <- matrix(1:9,nrow=3); Y <- matrix(1:16,nrow=4); Z <- matrix(1:4,nrow=2)
X;Y;Z
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3    6    9

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    5    9   13
#[2,]    2    6   10   14
#[3,]    3    7   11   15
#[4,]    4    8   12   16

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
```

Then a bunch of `Map`ping of the required indexes to a matrix, which is used to subset each of the `X`/`Y`/`Z` objects:

```
arep <- rep(1:nrow(A),nrow(B))
brep <- rep(1:nrow(B),each=nrow(A))
cells <- Map(
  `[`,
  list(X=X,Y=Y,Z=Z),
  Map(function(x,y) t(mapply(c,x,y)), A[arep,-1], B[brep,-1])
)

data.frame(A["A.ID"][arep,,drop=FALSE], B["B.ID"][brep,,drop=FALSE], cells)
#    A.ID B.ID X Y Z
#1      1    1 1 7 2
#2      2    1 2 6 1
#1.1    1    2 4 3 4
#2.1    2    2 5 2 3
```

Comment: `subscript out of bounds` probably refers to trying to select a row/column combination that is bigger than the `X/Y/Z` matrix it matches too. The `mapply` error may be because `A` and `B` don't have the same number of rows. There's plenty of possible reasons why these errors are thrown, but that is a couple ideas.

Comment: Hey thanks for this,

Sorry to pester you again but I also noticed that the data.frame function at the end didn't the permutations of A.ID and B.ID, then their corresponding values from X, Y and Z?

it looks like the result in your example is just lining up n with n.

The result i thought should look like this

 A  B X  Y  Z
(1, 1, 1, 7, 2)
(1, 2, 4, 3, 4) 
(2, 1, 2, 6, 1)
(2, 2, 5, 2, 3)

I tried generating this within the data.frame command with an expand.grid but this didn't work either. should I generate this list then attach the results of this mapping on?

Comment: Just one more thing I swear..

What if the values in A and B for columns X Y Z were names not numbers, rather names of the rows and cols of the matrices X Y Z?

This would change matrix A to (1, a, g, i),(2, b, e, h) and B to (1, a, e, h),(2, b, d, i). Then the row and column names for X = (a, b, c), Y = (d, e, f, g), Z = (h, i).

Also now i see why initial data would have been useful.. sorry for my lack of experience here!